# mySQL sorting issue with alphanumeric string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sorting

I have a purchased database with non-zero-padded alphanumeric golf course "numbers" like ZZ-1, ZZ-2, ZZ-9, ZZ-10...

I need to write a query which will pull the MAX numeric value and MAX when used on a string does not DWIM and sorts ZZ-9 as MAX over ZZ-10.

```
SELECT MAX( CourseNumber ) AS x
FROM courses
WHERE CourseNumber
RLIKE 'ZZ'
```

Same problem when only selecting the digits:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(CourseNumber, 4)) AS x 
FROM courses WHERE CourseNumber RLIKE 'ZZ'
```

Anyone have a clever way to do this?  I was think it must involve SUBSTR but I couldn't think how to make it work.

Comment: Are the alpha prefixes fixed-length, or are there 'PDQ' and 'ABCDFEGFGHIJLFERWEFDSFDS' prefixes as well? Either way, if you're doing a lot of searching/matching on those sub-fields, you may want to invest the time to pre-split those bits out into separate fields so you can do direct matching on those derived fields, otherwise your where clauses are going to turn into a hideous mess of substring/cast clauses.

Comment: At present they are all 2 letters, hyphen, numeral.  The people my boss bought this data from are idiots though so it may not stay that way forever but a solution assuming that pattern works for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(
  CAST(
    SUBSTRING(CourseNumber, 4) AS UNSIGNED)
  ) 
FROM courses WHERE CourseNumber RLIKE 'ZZ'
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe to_number(SUBSTR(coursenumber,3))

Comment: mySQL doesn't have to_number; I believe that's an Oracle function.

Comment: @jerry - yep im an Oracle guy at heart :)

Comment: Maybe something like SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(CourseNumber), 3) AS UNSIGNED) FROM courses WHERE CourseNumber RLIKE 'ZZ'

Comment: Randy - Googling to_number() set me on the right path!  Thanks!  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,152446,233605#msg-233605